# Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have used MongoDB3.0 with PHP version 5.3.5 and PHP Driver version 1.1.4. i have tried to insert record to collection i got Fatal error class Mongo client Not fount

insert.php

```
<?php   
       // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
   echo "Connection to database successfully";

   // select a database
   $db = $m->sample;
   echo "Database mydb selected";
   $collection = $db->testcoll;
   echo "Collection selected succsessfully";

   $document = array( 
      "title" => "MongoDB", 
      "description" => "database", 
      "likes" => 100,
      "url" => "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/",
      "by", "tutorials point"
   );

   $collection->insert($document);
   echo "Document inserted successfully";


?>
```

I have also attached PHP driver info [image]

Comment: try using `MongoDB\Driver\Manager`

Comment: again got `Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found `@Robert

Answer (score 1):

It is because this class was removed try using `http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php`

instead like this:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:2701");
```

Also mongo extension is not mongodb extension maybe you don't have MongoDB extension installed. Check [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.0.0 release you should use MongoDB\Driver\Manage

Most significantly, the legacy driver's MongoClient, MongoDB, and MongoCollection classes have been obsoleted by the MongoDB\Driver\Manager class, which is the new gateway for connecting and executing queries, commands, and write operations.

Source: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases/tag/1.0.0